# Constructor de una clase y constructor array

Tags: javascript, constructor

¿Porqué un constructor de una clase no me devuelve solamente el código que esta dentro de el?
Ej:

```
class Array{
constructor(x, y){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
}
}
let obj = new Array(false, true);
document.write(obj.constructor);// 
devuelve class Array{constructor(x, y) 
{this.a = a; this.b = b;}}
```

¿No debería devolver todo menos el class Array sus {}?

Y luego ¿porqué el constructor de un array es function Array{[native code]} y no class Array{constructor(){...}}?

Comment: Interesante pregunta, pero es bastante extensa mas de lo que parece, la respuesta se remonta a ES5 y anterior., tambien recuerda que  ya existe la clase `Array` por lo que no se si en este caso hay exactamente un conflicto de nombres al sobrescribir algo. o si el codigo nativo no se sobreescribe.

Answer (score 1):

En respuesta a:

> ¿porqué el constructor de un array es function Array{[native code]} y no class Array{constructor(){...}}?

A partir de `ES6` se introdujo [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) para la definición de clases. Antes de `ES6` se utilizaba el patrón [función constructora](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS#constructores_e_instancias_de_objetos) para lograr el mismo objetivo

Ejemplo:

```js
class cCoords {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
let coords = new cCoords(12, 54);
console.log(coords);
console.log(coords.constructor);

function fCoords (x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}
let coords2 = new fCoords(12, 54);
console.log(coords2);
console.log(coords2.constructor);
```

Answer (score 0):

No te devuelve lo mismo porque el caso específico de [Object.prototype.constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) , tiene la finalidad de "Retornar una referencia a la función del Object que creó el objeto de la instancia", osea simplemente en este caso particular tiene una función específica y distinta. Ejemplo:

```js
class Algo {
  constructor(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  unaFuncion() {
    //codigo
  }

}

let obj = new Algo("a", "b");

console.log(obj.constructor) // <-- La referencia al creador de la instancia

console.log(obj.unaFuncion) // <-- solo la función
```